# Unable to insert values in Table from variables

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am trying to insert the values into the table and i am unable to do this..
I am getting values from Enrty Widgets into a variable and putting them in DataBase but unfortunately i got error

I have tried this but getting error

```
G_Name = Namee
G_Day = Value.day
G_Month = Value.month
G_Year = Value.year

sql = "insert into Birthdays (Name, Day, Month, Year) VALUES (%s, %d, %d, 
%d) %"
val = (G_Name, G_Day, G_Month, G_Year)
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
```

It should insert values but i am getting following error:

```
"Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format- 
parameters; Python 'stringvar' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked on python 3.X but this is how it works on python 2.7

```
G_Name = Namee
G_Day = Value.day
G_Month = Value.month
G_Year = Value.year
mycursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)
sql = """ insert into Birthdays (Name, Day, Month, Year) VALUES (%s, %d, %d, %d)"""
val = (G_Name, G_Day, G_Month, G_Year)
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
connection.commit()
```

I don't know but that last % in your query is supposed to be there?.

Answer (score 0):

```
G_Name = str(En_Name.get())
```

i have corrected the error by using above statement
sql query cannot take StringVar() so i converted it to str then used it and it works